# Determine who (client or server) opened a socket in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Given a `Socket` alone (from `node:net`), how would I determine if this was a `Socket` that was created by a remote client connecting to my application or whether the `Socket` *is* the client? In other words, is there some way to check if a Socket is client-side or server-side?

Comment: If your application has opened the socket, can't it remember that fact?

Comment: This is for a library. I am making a function that takes a socket as an argument and applies event handlers to the socket, based on which is the server and which is the client. I am currently passing in an extra `boolean` indicating whether it is client-side, but I just wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution whereby I can use some information already present in the `Socket` to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

The same socket can be both a server (listening for incoming HTTP requests) and a client (making outgoing HTTP requests), as illustrated by the following code:

```js
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  http.get("http://localhost:8081", {localPort: 8080})
  .on("response", function(r) {
    res.write(`Client port ${req.client.remotePort}, server port 8080\n`);
    r.pipe(res);
  });
}).listen(8080);
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.end(`Client port ${req.client.remotePort}, server port 8081\n`);
}).listen(8081);
```

The request `GET http://localhost:8080` then draws the response

```
Client port 53778 (the browser), server port 8080 (socket as server)
Client port 8080 (socket as client), server port 8081 (second server)
```

Your question would then boil down do: Was the socket first created in its role as a server, or as a client? I don't think that the standard Node.js libraries leave a trace of that in the socket that they create. But you could put a boolean indicator into the socket yourself, rather than passing it as an extra parameter to your library function.